# Problema de CORS con CDN de Fontawesome

Tags: javascript, css, cors, font-awesome

Estoy trabajando con los iconos de fontawesome haciendo un llamado a la CDN que ofrece fontawesome, funcionaba correctamente, pero desde hace unos dias me arroja un error de CORS

```
0.0/css/all.css' from origin 'http://moonlight' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

No se a que se deba, no he cambiado nada, pero no me carga ningun icono, nisiquiera carga la libreria. Alguien tiene alguna idea de porque?

Comment: Falta mucha información para poder ayudarte, favor leer la sección: como preguntar?. El error de cors lo genera el navegador cuando un dominio intenta comunicarse con otro, habría que ver tu codigo, está local, está deployado, donde?, si está deployado en un http sin seguridad también puede dar problemas. En fin, trata de dar información útil para identificar tu problema, de otra manera es imposible ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de CORS no lo pude resolver, pero buscando informacion al respecto me tope con que suele pasar mucho y hasta ahora no se ha dado una solucion oficial. Puede deberse a muchos problemas diferentes y no siempre das con la solucion, asi que opte por usar una version anterior de FontAwesome y me funcionó.

Actualmente, FontAwesome ofrecía la CDN Pro de forma gratuita, almenos así me aparecía a mi, y me funcionaba, por eso empecé a usar iconos de la versión Pro, y luego de este problema tuve que volver a la versión Free y con ello a usar los `iconos solid`, y digamos que no se ven como quisiera. Encontré una solución aunque no se que tan legal sea publicarla...

Me pasaron un enlace de Drive con la librería descargada, lo único que tuve que hacer fue copiarla a mi proyecto y llamar al archivo all.css.

Como dije, no se que tan legal sea esto, o si esta permitido publicarlo aquí, pero, espero os ayude.

Comment: No es legal, ni ético.